# We'd rather be in a state within a state

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> We'd rather be in a state within a state
>
> I said that’s where we wanted to go to to my dog
>
> “Z" is half of where I am. I’m called a wreath in another life. But now, I'm called exactly how I got here.
>
> All my dreaming lead me here, no pot of gold at the end of this rainbow; though for the first time, its colors show
>
> Reality is twice removed. Three ticks will get me half-way there
>
> Do you know who I am?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mostly explained below, but I'm unsure about the second line now.

You are

> **DOROTHY GALE**
> Currently residing in Oz, wanting to return home

We'd rather be in a state within a state

> From @EightAndAHalfTails: She'd rather be in **KANSAS**, whose letters are part of a different state, AR**KANSAS**

I said that’s where we wanted to go to to my dog

> She sings about going "somewhere over the rainbow" to Toto (her dog)
> I'm unsure about this line, because the clue sounds to me like she's in Oz telling Toto she wanted to go home (may have happened, can't recall), but my answer is her at home telling Toto she wants to go to Oz.

“Z" is half of where I am.

> Z is half of O**Z**

I’m called a wreath in another life.

> From @TwoBitOperation: Dorothy's actress is Judy **Garland**

But now, I'm called exactly how I got here.

> Now she's Dorothy **Gale**, which relates to the twister that whisked her away to Oz

All my dreaming lead me here

> It was all a dream...or was it?

no pot of gold at the end of this rainbow

> Oz is "somewhere over the rainbow".  While it has "yellow bricks" and an Emerald City, there are no pots of gold

though for the first time, its colors show

> From @F1Krazy: When she arrives in Oz, the film goes from black-and-white to technicolor.

Reality is twice removed.

> From @EightAndAHalfTails: Our reality -> Kansas/"home" inside the film -> Oz/dream

Three ticks will get me half-way there

> To get home, she has to click her heels AND say "There's no place like home" three times

Do you know who I am?

> Dorothy Gale

Also

> First letter of each line = WIZARD

Comment: I think this is most certainly the answer. Perhaps the first line is rot13(Ersrerapvat Zhapuxva ynaq, juvpu vf va gur ynaq bs BM?)

Comment: And the wreath line works because rot13: Gur npgerff'f anzr jnf Whql 'Tneynaq'

Comment: @Joe-You-Know That could be it.  Thanks, I've added it in.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Ahh, yeah, that definitely fits.  Thank you.

Comment: "Though for the first time, its colours show" - Rot13: Nsgre Qbebgul neevirf va Bm, gur svyz genafvgvbaf sebz oynpx-naq-juvgr gb Grpuavpbybe.

Comment: @F1Krazy Ha, I just realized what it was when reading the first part of your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: Right about almost everything! "n fgngr jvguva n fgngr" vf abg ersreevat gb Zhapuxva Ynaq (gung'f abg ernyyl jurer gurl'q engure or). Ernyyl pybfr ba "Ernyvgl vf gjvpr erzbirq". And F1Krazy is right. Great work!

Answer (score 6):

Partial answers that hagfy missed:

We'd rather be in a state within a state

> She'd rather be in Kansas, which is a US state 'within' another US state, ArKANSAS

Reality is twice removed. Three ticks will get me half-way there

> Even after returning to Kansas, she's not in reality (our world); she's in the film "The Wizard of Oz"

Comment: These seem good, so I've added them to my answer.  Thanks!